# Rails generate creates files in the original directory instead of the directory copy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv

I created a copy of a rails directory (let's say "A") and then CD'd to that copy (let's say "B") and  tried to execute 'rails generate' but the files are generated in the original directory ("A"). I am also using rbenv and I'm wondering if some magic is happening to cause this behaviour. I am also developing on OSX Yosemite. Anyone have any clue? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I think the problem might be due to the Spring gem.

Comment: There's no magic. You're saying you copied directory A to directory B `cp -r ./a ./b` and then you changed directory to B (`cd ../b`) and then in B did ran `rails g some_app`? Its really hard to understand why you'd do that since the copy of a rails dir (a) would be a rails dir (b).

Comment: Directory B is a copy of directory A, A and B are siblings. A is not in B, if that is what you are thinking.

Comment: Right -- A is a copy of B -- if A is a generated rails app, B will be too since you copied the directory. If i copy a rails app, the copy is also a rails app. So you wouldn't need to generate it again. There's definitely no magic involved so maybe describing what you're trying to _do_ would help.

Comment: In B I'm trying to generate a new controller. I don't want it to be in A.

Answer (score -1):

You might have make soft copy of directory A. I mean you made it symbolink of A. Let me explain symbolink, symbolink is basically make virtual copy of original directory, but original directory remains same. and whatever changes you do in new directory, they are effected in original directory.

Comment: This is a great point -- a soft copy would totally behave like that.

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem might be due to the Spring gem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem appears to be with the Spring gem. After stopping the Spring process and uninstalling it I was able to create the controller in the directory. I'm a Rails newbie and didn't realize what Spring did. It keeps your Rails application running in the background and it also changes the rails binaries to implement its functionality. So when I copied that directory to a new one. I theorize that all the changes I wanted to make to the copy were somehow being redirected to the old one because the old directory was where the Spring process was started. Ugh.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It solved my problem and may be helpful to people new to Rails 4.